# Configures locale not being considered

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-7

My software relies in the windows locale configuration to work properly.

My customers have always the pt-br locale setted up and it works fine that way.

In one user´s windows there is the pt-br locale setted properly but somehow my software gets all the us configurations. (. as decimal sepparator, $ as currency symbol and so on).

Is there any way for me to force the locale globally in my software?

Comment: Is this on an installation of windows 7 where you choosed the locale in the installation phase? Try to change locale to something else, save, and then  change back again.

Comment: This could be a problem specific to that Windows installation. Forcing your software to use a specific locate is not recommended. I suggest you to debug the Windows installation/registry instead.

Comment: No, this is not an installation issue, but a setting issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have delphi-7 you can do as follows:

> Application.UpdateFormatSettings := false;

This prevents the system to update your application with windows default values.

Then define at application startup:

```
DecimalSeparator := '.'; // Or whatever preference you have
CurrencyString := '$'; // Or something else
... 
etc
```

In Delphi 2006 and higher this method is deprecated and the use of `TFormatSettings` is prefered. It also deals with reentrancy problems if parts of the applications needs to change the format settings during execution.

Comment: Issue is about detection of the system locale, not about how to set the locale settings at runtime. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem I found your post.

I also found this thread (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/b4f90f07-206c-494b-8d14-ee17bfa689e0) that helped me.

Here's the method:

> If you open "Regional and Language Options" from the control panel
>   (the globe icon) / intl.cpl, and reselect your locale it will likely
>   solve the problem.
>
> 1) Open Regional and Language Options
>
> 2) Under "Format" pick anything else. (eg: English (United States)).
>
> 3) Press "Apply"
>
> 4) Under "Format" pick your desired locale (eg: English (United
>   Kingdom)).
>
> 5) Press OK.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows Seven, the locale of non Unicode apps (like Delphi 7) is not set in the main tab of the Control Panel.

You will have to go to "Administrative" tab, then select "Change system locale".

[image]

See [this article](http://www.coscom.co.jp/japanesefont/nonunicode_win7.html).